# How to STRING_SPLIT where there are too many commagules?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question about the `STRING_SPLIT`. I need to separate phrases inside a String, separated by comma. The problem is that some of these phrases have around them, more commas.

This is an example:

1. Archiviazione, 2. Conservazione in archivi**,** ad accesso selezionato, 3. Conservazione in contenitori muniti di serratura, 4. Controllo degli accessi fisici, 5. Controllo degli accessi logici, 6. Custodia atti e documenti, 7. Formazione degli incaricati, 8. Sicurezza dei siti web

As you can see, within item 2 there is a comma that hinders the process of division by comma. How can I overcome this situation?

Another question would be: is there a way to pass a parameter to the `String_Split` where the number with dot next can serve as a separator instead of the comma?

Thank you very much from now on!

With the query:

```
select * 
from string_split('1. Archiviazione, 2. Conservazione in archivi, ad accesso selezionato, 3. Conservazione in contenitori muniti di serratura, 4. Controllo degli accessi fisici, 5. Controllo degli accessi logici, 6. Custodia atti e documenti, 7. Formazione degli incaricati, 8. Sicurezza dei siti web', ',')
```

I got this result:

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (string_split is product specific.)

Comment: The best way to overcome the problem is to use a delimiter that will never be in the values (e.g. `|`).

Comment: I think the best way is to save the different parts in separate rows or columns

Comment: What is a "commagules"? Based on the data, I thought it might be something from a different language, but [Google has no idea](https://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=commagules) either.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little ugly, and certainly some risk involved, but using JSON may be an alternative

```
Select value
 From  ( 
        Select [key]
              ,Value   = case when trim(Value) like '[0-9]%' then trim(Value) else null end
                         +case when lead(trim(Value),1,'') over (order by [key]) like '[0-9]%' 
                              then ''
                              else ', '+lead(trim(Value),1,'') over (order by [key]) 
                          end
        From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape('1. Archiviazione, 2. Conservazione in archivi, ad accesso selezionato, 3. Conservazione in contenitori muniti di serratura, 4. Controllo degli accessi fisici, 5. Controllo degli accessi logici, 6. Custodia atti e documenti, 7. Formazione degli incaricati, 8. Sicurezza dei siti web','json'),',','","')+'"]' )
       ) A
Where Value is not null
Order By [key]
```

**Results**

```
1. Archiviazione
2. Conservazione in archivi, ad accesso selezionato
3. Conservazione in contenitori muniti di serratura
4. Controllo degli accessi fisici
5. Controllo degli accessi logici
6. Custodia atti e documenti
7. Formazione degli incaricati
8. Sicurezza dei siti web
```

Answer (score 2):

To the other answers, it is of course better to separate the data in a more appropriate fashion on input. When you are faced with existing data, `STRING_SPLIT` will not do what you are looking for so you will need to "parse the string manually". I would search back for SQL answers prior to the availability of `STRING_SPLIT` for good references on this type of logic, however some other features have come out since that makes this a little nicer.

Because your format is based on incrementing numbers, you can take advantage of the following steps:
a) Generate a "numbers" table/subquery and make a string for each number , eg. '1.' '2.' '3.', etc...
b) Find the `PATINDEX` of each number as well as the `PATINDEX` of the "next" number via `LEAD`
c) Use the two indices to create parameters for `SUBSTRING` and do some string cleanup

See below for a sample query that will split the substrings. You could replace @theString with an iTVF parameter or however you need to apply this in your code.

```
    DECLARE @theString VARCHAR(MAX) = '1. Archiviazione, 2. Conservazione in archivi**,** ad accesso selezionato, 3. Conservazione in contenitori muniti di serratura, 4. Controllo degli accessi fisici, 5. Controllo degli accessi logici, 6. Custodia atti e documenti, 7. Formazione degli incaricati, 8. Sicurezza dei siti web'

--SET @theString = '1. Apples, 2. Oranges, 3. Peaches, 4. Pears, 5. Cheese, 6. Kiwis, 7. Toast'
;WITH CTE_Nums AS
(
    SELECT CONCAT(', ',CAST([NumValue] AS VARCHAR(10)),'. ') [NumString],[NumValue]
    FROM (
        SELECT ones.n + tens.n * 10 + huns.n * 100 [NumValue]
        FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
             (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
             (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) huns(n)
        ) n1
)
SELECT 
    N.NumValue,
    N.Pos1,
    f1.Pos1 pos1f,
    N.Pos2,
    f1.Pos2 pos2f,
    f1.Pos2 - N.Pos1 SubLen,
    SUBSTRING(@theString,f1.Pos1,(f1.Pos2 - f1.Pos1 ) ) SubStr
FROM
    ( SELECT 
        nn.NumValue,
        PATINDEX('%'+nn.[NumString]+'%',@theString) Pos1,
        PATINDEX('%'+ LEAD(nn.[NumString]) OVER ( ORDER BY nn.NumValue ASC ) + '%',@theString) Pos2
        FROM 
        CTE_Nums nn
    ) N
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT IIF(N.NumValue = 1,N.Pos1,N.Pos1+LEN(',-')) Pos1,
    IIF(N.Pos2 > 0,N.Pos2,LEN(@theString)) Pos2 ) f1
WHERE
    N.Pos1 > 0 OR N.NumValue = 1
ORDER BY 
    N.NumValue ASC
```

I have left the other columns but the [SubStr] column is the one you want that returns:

> 1. Archiviazione
> 2. Conservazione in archivi**,** ad accesso selezionato
> 3. Conservazione in contenitori muniti di serratura
> 4. Controllo degli accessi fisici
> 5. Controllo degli accessi logici
> 6. Custodia atti e documenti
> 7. Formazione degli incaricati
> 8. Sicurezza dei siti we